# Why does this Android Volley request never complete?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-volley

Consider this code in an Android activity, using the Volley HTTP library. The HTTP request never completes. It neither receives a normal response nor an error response. But if the `while (!done)` block is commented out, then everything completes normally. This surprises me since with Volley I'm making a `RequestQueue` which contains a thread pool where entirely separate threads are used to carry out the HTTP request. So why does the request never finish if this thread is sleeping?

The code:

```
package com.adobe.instore.activities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.adobe.instore.R;
import com.adobe.instore.Urls;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class VolleyTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_volley_test);
    }

    private static boolean done = false;
    protected void makeRequest(View v) {
        Log.i(getLocalClassName(), "Request");

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        queue.start();
        queue.add(new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, Urls.STATIC_URL + "/profiles.json", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.i(getLocalClassName(), "Response");
                done = true;
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(getLocalClassName(), "Error");
            }
        }));

        Log.i(getLocalClassName(), "Awaiting completion");
        while(!done) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Log.i(getLocalClassName(), "Done");
    }
}
```

Comment: why you say never finish?

Comment: @josedlujan The application hangs without printing the expected text to the logcat console.

Comment: Remove your while loop it is blocking the main thread.

Comment: @Enzokie that'd fix it, but he's wondering *why*.  Although, I'm not sure why you'd ever want to sleep on the main thread.

Comment: @Submersed think of a thread as a real life Employee, if you tell the employee to sleep and it has many jobs to do I would doubt that it would finish its task on time and the boss will surely be angry, when you say *separate thread* it just means you are asking other employee to help you in this job, in that case your MAIN employee will be able to his job since somebody is helping him :)

Comment: `I'm not sure why you'd ever want to sleep on the main thread` Activity runs on the Main thread, therefore if you put a Thread.sleep much worst within a loop, it will certainly block.

Comment: @Enzokie I have a pretty strong concept of threads.  My statement was basically to say that you *shouldn't* be sleeping on the main thread.  I was more referencing the context of the question, since he's already expressed that removing it fixes the issue.

Comment: @Submersed but your code is explicitly saying "please sleep main thread". Android don't impose a restriction on that but it is a bad idea to begin with. Executions are not always queued in the thread base on how your code is ordered linearly written.

Comment: This `while(!done)` will cause an infinite loop since done is always be `!false` means `true`. And the other executions are not gonna make it. Your are expecting that `onResponse` will be called next but not gonna happen (Because volley use a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) with [Looper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#getMainLooper()) from the Main thread). That also means that volatile will make no use at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views are rendered in the Main Thread (sometimes called UI Thread). The loop you made blocks the rendering and the other code that follows. Technically it is a bad idea to call `Thread.sleep(...);` in this thread since many things will be affected. Volley is a http library designed to make your life simpler by not needing to explicitly call a Thread of your own.

In Volley all the networking and cache dispatching are done in a Separate thread (behind the hood) while the response is sent back to the Main thread. That just means that `onResponse` and `onError` happens in the Main thread.

To make it more simpler you can do like this:

```
public class VolleyTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_volley_test);
    }

    public void makeRequest(View v) {
        Log.i(getLocalClassName(), "Request");

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        queue.start();
        queue.add(new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, Urls.STATIC_URL + "/profiles.json", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.i(getLocalClassName(), "Response");
                Log.i(getLocalClassName(), "Done");
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(getLocalClassName(), "Error");
            }
        }));

        Log.i(getLocalClassName(), "Awaiting completion");
    }
}
```

Furthermore the `while()` and `Thread.sleep` keeps the Thread busy. So any executions queued in the Main thread are unreachable till the loop is done (but it wont happen). You might be thinking that the `onResponse` can bypass that infinite loop? The answer is NO; because `onResponse` is queued by the Main thread and not the background Thread. To illustrate see figure below:
[image]

*Figure 1 : Android Volley internal architecture (image is from the docs)*

If you look that box that says **Parsed response delivered on main thread** which is colored as BLUE meaning it is the Main thread who call it (to simplify it means `onResponse` and `onError` are called by the Main thread) unless it is orange or green then loop will be bypassed by your boolean.

Comment: Yes, I was under the mistaken impression that the thread pool threads would be the ones running the `onResponse` and `onError` code. Thanks for clarifying the situation!

Answer (score 1):

Volley onResponse and onErrorResponse is called on UI thread. So if your main thread is sleeping, then onResponse and onErrorResponse will not be called

Comment: Should I just create a `new Thread()` to offload the waiting? Or is there a more Android-y way of doing things?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: turns out I was confused about what was wrong in my application. I was trying something tricky with async HTTP calls but it turned out I just had an unrelated bug. Thanks